# Set background color on MoreNavigationsController Swift 2

Tags: colors, background, swift2, uitabcontroller

I try to set to background color to the "more" tab in may tabController but it wont change.. I have try this

```
self.moreNavigationController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Bar:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Replace greenColor with whatever UIColor you want

Comment: Thanks for your help. This change background on navigationBar "More". How to change the background on the hole list view when you had clicked on "more" ?